# User-created vs System-created Access Teams

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In CRM, there are two types of Access Teams: User-created and System-created. As per my understanding, the User-created Access Teams are suitable for scenarios where **multiple records have to be shared with an Access Team with different access rights**. On the other hand, the System-created Access Teams are suitable for scenarios where **each record has to be shared with a unique set of Access Team but with the same access rights**.

1. Is this understanding correct?
2. Other than this conceptual difference, is there any difference in how the POA table gets generated in both the scenarios behind-the-scene? For example, suppose that we have a requirement where there will be a unique set of users having access to each record. So the obvious choice in this scenario would be to use System-created Access Team so that each record will have its own set of access users. However, another approach that can be implemented here is to create one User-created Access Team per record and share each record with this Access Team. I assume that internally for CRM both the approaches are similar since one sharing operation has to take place with either of the approaches. Or is there any other difference that I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your understanding is [correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481569.aspx#Quick%20reference%20to%20teams)

[image]

2. No difference. This works like [sharing](http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/access-teams-why-do-we-really-need-them/), in fact teams sharing will create only one POA entry [compared](http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/poa-what-it-looks-like-on-the-sql-side/) to multiple POA entries for individual users sharing